# Emberjs TODO-list. cannot create new 'todo'

Tags: ember.js, controller, assertions

I am trying make a remake of the todo list with a different name called 'newpermitcategory'. My code seems to match the examples on the emberjs website but i am still receiving this error when I try to make a new permittype (todo).

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'trim' of undefined
```

**I spelled the plural of newpermitcategory as newpermitcategorys on purpose.

This is the code

```
<h2>New Permit Category</h2> 
  {{input type="text" id="newpermitcategory" placeholder="Create a category and press enter" value=newPermittype action="createPermitcategory"}}
<tr id="newpermitcategory">
{{#each}}
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
    <label>{{permittype}}</label> lol
  </td>
{{/each}}
</tr>

VpcYeoman.NewpermitcategorysController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    createPermitcategory: function () {
      var permittype = this.get('newPermittype');
      if (!permittype.trim()) {return;}

      var newpermitcategory = this.store.createRecord('newpermitcategory', {
        permittype: permittype
      });

      this.set('newPermittype', '');

      newpermitcategory.save();
    }
  }
});

VpcYeoman.Newpermitcategory = DS.Model.extend({
    permittype: DS.attr('string'),
    isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean')
});

VpcYeoman.Newpermitcategory.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    permittype:'Building'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    permitType:'Electrical'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    permittype:'Zoning'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    permittype:'Fire'
  }
];


VpcYeoman.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('newpermitcategorys', { path: '/newpermitcategorys' });
  this.resource('newpermitcategory', { path: '/newpermitcategory/:newpermitcategory_id' });
});

VpcYeoman.NewpermitcategoryView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'newpermitcategory'
});

VpcYeoman.NewpermitcategorysView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'newpermitcategorys'
});


VpcYeoman.NewpermitcategorysRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('newpermitcategory');
  }
});

VpcYeoman.Newpermitcategoryroute = Ember.Route.extend({

});
```

EDIT: I had originally made a lot of capitalization mistakes. Naming conventions are so important in Emberjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your route and controller names are incorrect

NewpermitcategorysController

NewpermitcategorysRoute

NewpermitcategoryView

and your action name doesn't match

createPermitcategory and createPermitCategory

and the field `newPermittype` doesn't exist, you are setting the input value to a constant `"newPermittype"` not the field `newPermittype`

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/15/edit

Comment: You are correct. Those errors have been fixed. The input now displays, except when I type in a new permittype and hit enter, it says 'Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the event 'createPermitcategory'.' I have updated the question.

Comment: ArrayConroller missing a t

Comment: NewPermitCategorysController should also be NewpermitcategorysController

Comment: Apologies. I am still correcting the caps of all the names in my code and this post. I decided to take out caps in other places as well 'newPermittype' vs 'newPermitType'

Comment: If your model type is `Newpermitcategory`, then Ember Data will pluralize this as Newpermitcategories, right?  So in that case it is looking for NewpermitcategoriesController

Comment: ED doesn't build the controllers/route/views.

Comment: @kingpin2k it's displaying the same error. I'm going to try Steve's suggestion and then I will update this comment. I created everything by hand and I assumed that if the names remained consistent, that I would be able to add an 's' at the end of a plural and emberjs will recognize it regardless of whether it is the actual spelling of the word. I am also using Yeoman.

Comment: the action names don't match either, see above

Comment: "{{input type="text" id="newpermitcategory" placeholder="Create a category and press enter" value="newPermittype" action="createPermitcategory"}}" calls the action.

Comment: createPermitcategory is different than createPermitCategory, the error should be nothing handled the event `createPermitcategory`

Comment: Success! This solved it. Thanks Kingpin. Someday I will pay you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43139/discussion-between-kingpin2k-and-ian-steffy)